# How to resize flexbox to match screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my flexbox (i think) for my website. The flex box actually does work but it goes way down (*see pictures attached*).

I found online that I have to use % instead of fixed sizes which I did and it does not seem to fix the problem.  I also tried to use block methods but then it does a scroll bar but i want it to adapt to even phone screen resolutions or at least just look good when I resize my browser page, which it does not right now.

I can't seem to find another solution as the other features do resize correctly, it's just that  that goes way too down upon resizing.

[It is like this on a smaller resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukJ2h.jpg)

[when it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGsjK.jpg)

Here is my CSS code for that part :

```
.products_page{
    
    max-width:80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: -41%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
   
  }

.products_page div{
  
    display:block;
    margin:1%;
    line-height: 20%;
  
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing you html it's hard to identify the problem however try adding `align-content: flex-start` to the .products_page class

Comment: If you can provide us with your html code, this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, but it takes more time and requires writing code:
You put each 3 "div" in a separate "div" eg a div named "row",
then:

```
.products_page{
    width:80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    display: grid;
place-items: center;
    margin-top: -41%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
  }

.products_page .row{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
}
```

And remove "margin" from ".products_page div".

It's done, it shows these elements as in [this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGsjK.jpg).

Now our task is to view the phone:

```
@media only all and (max-width: 1000px){
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: center;
}
```

I can't guarantee that this will work 100%, but you can try!

Answer (score 0):

In your design, you are fitting 3 elements on each row. The best way to do it in **flexbox** is by going through `flex: 33.33%`:

### Code:

```css
.products_page{
    
    max-width:80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: -41%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
   
}

.products_page div{
    flex: 33.33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of **fixed sizes and percentages** in your CSS, in my opinion, is what's causing the problem you've been having.

```
.products_page{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 2%;
}

.products_page div{
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 2%);
  margin: 1%;
  line-height: 20%;
}
```

Try to modify your CSS as follows.